# reducint the template noise from gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I have read a number of questions regarding this issue, but the most recent answer I found was dated 2012, so I'm wondering if things have changed in the meantime.

When print output for a std container for example, the signal to noise ratio is poor for out of the box gdb.  What is the current state-of-the-art or best practices for improving the signal to noise ratio?  I'd like a low level of detail by default, but optionally be able to turn on a higher level as needed.

Comment: Add an example? It might be good to clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: which gdb version you checked lately?